# jQuery Accordion arrow icons with seperate close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I've got an accordion with arrow icons indicating when a section is open and closed. Once the accordion is opened the arrow points down showing the content below it.

However I've created a close button that gets appended into each section. This sits at the bottom of every section in the accordion.

I want it so that once the close button is pressed the arrow changes it's state back to closed.

```
$(function() {
$('#accordion h3').each(function(){ 
    var $set = $(this).nextUntil("h3");
    $set.wrapAll('<div />');
});

$('#accordion').accordion({ collapsible:true, active:true, heightStyle:"content", disabled:true, animated: false});
$('.ui-accordion-header').bind('click',function(){
    theOffset = $(this).offset();
    $(window).scrollTop(theOffset.top - 50);
});

$('#accordion h3.ui-accordion-header').click(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    $('.ui-accordion-header-icon', _this).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
    _this.next().slideToggle();
    return false;
});

    $('.ui-accordion-content').append('<a href="#" class="close">Close</a><div class="clearfix"></div>');

    $('.close').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
        $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function(){
            $(window).scrollTop(theOffset.top - 50);
            var hidecollapsebutton = true;
            $('.ui-accordion-content').each(function(){
                if($(this).css('display') == 'block')
                {
                    hidecollapsebutton = false;
                }
            });

            if(hidecollapsebutton)
            {
                $('.accordion-expand-all').show();
                $('.accordion-collapse-all').hide();
            }

        });

        return false;
    })

});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I can provide more information if it's needed. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/EZT6A/

Comment: Would you reproduce in jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EZT6A/ @Michał

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
```

As you could have found out yourself with a little simple debugging, `$(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content')` does not match any element here. (That’s because your close button is within `div.ui-accordion-content`, and the `h3.ui-accordion-header` is the previous sibling of that `div` element.)

Simple to fix: Go up to parent `div` (`.ui-accordion-content`), get previous `h3` (`.ui-accordion-header`), and then the `span` (`.ui-accordion-header-icon`) element within it:

```
$(this).parents('.ui-accordion-content')
  .prev('.ui-accordion-header')
  .find('.ui-accordion-header-icon')
  .removeClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s')
  .addClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EZT6A/2/

Comment: Thanks. Sorry jQuery's not my strong point but I'm getting there

Comment: No Problem. I first did a `console.log($(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content'))` at the beginning of your click handler function, and got an empty object in console … simple starting point for debugging issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try changing `click` to `on`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".close", function(){
   //change arrow state
});
```

It's because not every `.close` element exist as you binding `click` event.